# I need help this is urgent! Pls respond! Pls respond! Pls!

Tags: salat, practical-islam

When I pray and I get to Surat al Fatihah I keep on repeating al ham and I know it’s al hamdu lillahi rabbil alameen but I keep on repeating it. After some time I get frustrated and I think if this keeps on happening I will stop praying. I don’t want to stop praying. I keep on repeating other surah’s as well. I don’t know what’s happening to me I can’t describe what is happening to me I need help. I used to pray so good but know I can’t even pray correctly. It’s not that I can’t read surah al Fatihah it’s just this thing happening to me in my prayer. I can’t describe what happening in my prayer on Allah (S.W.T) know what happening to me how can I get Allah’s help if I don’t pray. I need Allah’s help to get my prayer correct. So how can I seek Allah’s help? I heard that you have to seek Allah’s help by praying but that’s not an option for me. I also did dua to Allah (S.W.T) for help but I don’t think the dua worked. I feel hopeless. I keep on saying to my self that the only option is to stop praying but I won’t stop praying but I can’t pray. I tried reciting surah al Fatihah from the Quran but that also didn’t work pls help pls pls I need urgent help pls help I don’t want to go to hell pls help pls pls pls

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Allah doesn't see your way of reciting surahs in salah, he just watches your heart, if you love allah and you offer salah for the sake of him then your salah is of high level whether you think this the weakest salah of your life. Practice surah al fatiha in nafl prayer,try to repeat it less, say alhamdu and then stop and then say lillahi and then stop and then say rabbill and then stop and then say aalamin, it will take time but don't worry. Always remember that Allah is with you.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Recite surah fatiha many times sothat you can get used to it. Recite slowly and correctly. Read translation. Its not hard to overcome this problem. And you should fix this ASAP. Because PROPHET Muhammad (PBUH) said that prayer is not valid if someone doesn't recite umm al Qur'an (SURAH FATIHA). Now, i am not stating that your prayers are not valid. Only Allah knows whether your prayers are valid or not. But fixing this problem is not that much difficult.

Edit:-
It would be better to ask someone for help. Ask a aalim(scholar) or just someone who can recite the Qu'ran correctly to help you. Don't worry everything will be OKAY IN SHA ALLAH. Your main problem is actually your frustration when you want to do good but you just couldn't do. Talk to someone, you will feel good and then start practising. Be calm!

And Allah knows best.